# C API mysql not returning result set

Tags: mysql, c

I have a situation where I am making serial SELECT queries to a table on a LAMP box using the C api. The first query select a single record (an order header). The second query then uses the returned record number from the first query to select the line items which are indexed by the order header record number. The first query works fine, the second query always returns zero rows (either by checking mysql_fetch_numrows() or a while loop doing mysql_fetchrow()). I print out the SQL on the console and then copy and paste it into the MySQL client. It returns the expected 3 records that I see in the DB. This leads me to the conclusion that the SQL statement is correct.

I do a mysql_free_result() call after each query. Since I don't have a ton of experience using the C API I'm wondering if there is something else I have to close or free up. The sequence of events is:

```
mysql_init()
mysql_real_connect()
mysql_query()
mysql_store_result()
mysql_fetch_row()
mysql_free_result()
mysql_query()
mysql_store_result()
mysql_fetch_row()        <--- fails, no error code, zero rows returned
```

The only global variable involved in all this is the connection handle.

Comment: Are you checking that none of the previous functions fail? Also, you do not mysql_free_result() beetween the last mysql_query and before the last mysql_fetch_row() ?

I would recommend to check without any free_result() and then re-introduce them one by one if it comes from them.

Comment: @JeremyCochoy I check the status after each function call and they all succeed. I perform a single query, process the results, mysql_free_results(), then another query. There is only one free_results() call required between the two queries (I clean up after the second query, but that wasn't germane to the question).

Comment: Without more informations, it's hard to say. What's currently written in the question seams a correct usage.

Comment: @JeremyCochoy hence my dilemma. I SEEM to be doing everything correctly, just no results.

Comment: @mlewis54 - Maybe adding some real code to the question might be useful for us to troubleshoot your issue. Do you have binary data in your query? If so, use `mysql_real_query()` instead. What is the result of second `mysql_query()`? Should be `0`; what does second `mysql_store_result()` returns? If NULL then might your data be too big to be allocated? As `mysql_store_result()` will load the whole resultset into memory (memory table or buffer). See what `mysql_error()` or `mysql_errno()` gives you after the second `mysql_store_result()`. I understood that `mysql_num_rows()` gives you 0 rows. :)

Comment: @ludesign No binary data, the result of the query is 0, the second store_result returns success. The data returned is about 100 bytes. mysql_errno=0. It even knows there are three fields that are supposed to be returned from the query. Everything seems to look like it works. It's almost as if it's a normal call that just didn't return results. However, if I cut and paste the sql (which I print out before the call) into the mysql client it returns the expected 3 records.

Comment: @mlewis54 - This is very strange. Could you try to run the query of second mysql_query() without the WHERE clause and then by adding OR 1=1 and see if it will give you something back. At the moment I cannot think of anything else. These queries should give you all the rows from your targeted table. Could you post the code you are using to build the second query?

Comment: I can't return everything, there are 135 million+ records in the table. The code is a generalized routine that is used in 50 places in the program. It works everywhere else (even with repeated calls in other locations). I am beginning to suspect that something else in the program may be trashing memory in one of the MySQL structs.

Comment: @mlewis54 - Watch the queries with `mtop` or trace them via other methods to see what is happening with the query when send to mysql. Also try to debug your program with `strace` and `dbg` if you suspect memory management issues; If I can be of any help, let me know. ;)